# Jquery Horizontal Scrolling Timeline

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, timeline

I have had a look around a lot of plugins but I can't seem to find one that would have the same functionality as this one. http://global.penguinrandomhouse.com/company-history/

Does someone know one ?

Thank you in advance.